# I need a study guide for linear algebraic expressions.

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

this is my first post on Stack Exchange.

I need a study guide for linear algebraic expressions.

I am good at vector analysis and calculus, but not so good at linear algebra.

Image :
[image: Image Set]

In the image above, is the part I have colored in blue a linear algebraic expression? I am having trouble searching and learning this. I can't type expressions by math symbols into the Google search bar. I can't find a proper interpretation of the formula and just figure out what it means from the context. I'm not even sure if that's a linear algebraic expression. Is my only option to take my time and study a linear algebra textbook sequentially?

I apologize if this question doesn't fit into the Stack Exchange.

Comment: Those aren't formulas. They appear to be sets.

Answer (score 1):

Here , the $\{I_m\}^M$ is not some Polynomial or Matrix or vector which you can  Solve / manipulate. That is a Set , in non-standard notation , where the SuperScript indicates the Size of the Set. The elements are Images , whose format is not given in that Small Snippet , though that format might be some Matrix or Sequence of real numbers.

The $\{\Omega_{4 \times 4}^m\}^M$ is a Set with $M$ Matrix elements whose sizes are $4 \times 4$ , where SuperScript $m$ corresponds to the Image element.
It looks like this Matrix gives the Camera Orientations / Camera Positions / Camera Angles though which the corresponding Image was taken.
The Small Snippet has no Details about the $4 \times 4 = 16$ elements in each Matrix.

Problem given is to "Computationally" generate the Images when the Camera Orientations / Camera Positions / Camera angles are given. There are $k$ such elements given , whose Images have to be generated.

It is Image Processing Problem.
Solution might necessitate knowing Linear Algebra , Differential Calculus , Numerical Methods , geometry , trigonometry , Etc.
You need Image Processing Study Guide. Working with linear algebraic expressions is a very tiny Part here.

The text book you are using will have Details about the notation used & it will also give the necessary background theory , including further references.